# Flickr/FlickrNet results to Razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, flickr

I'm working in .NET Core with the FlickrNet NuGet package, which I use to retrieve images from Flickr:

```
PhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosSearch(options);
```

The above successfully retrieves a collection of photos.  However I struggling to work out how to pass these to the Razor View.  Normally one returns a view with a model, but here I want to return a generic collection.  How should I go about this?

```
@using FlickrNet
@List<PhotoCollection> photos
```

How do I return the PhotoCollection to the Razor view for display?

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with the @List<PhotoCollection> photos in my Razor page: 'using generic type list requires 1 type arguments'. I need to change this...

Comment: It's probably in the view `@model PhotoCollection` and in the controller action `return View(photos)`

Comment: Thanks @Jasen!  Yes it was: @model FlickrNet.PhotoCollection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/samjudson/flickr-net/tree/master/FlickrNet) we can see that `PhotoCollection` extends `PagedPhotoCollection` which extends `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Photo>`

So ultimately your model is `Collection<Photo>`.

Your view would then be

```
@using FlickrNet
@model PhotoCollection

<div>Page Number: @Model.Page</div>

@foreach(var photo in Model)
{
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    ...
}
```

And your controller

```
public ActionResult GetPhotos()
{
    PhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotoSearch(options);

    return View(photos);
}
```